# Agregar información a índice en un arreglo php

Tags: php, jquery, array

podrían ayudarme a ver como lograr esto:

Tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
         array1=[{
         id: "72",
         rfc: "iyuiiygjgj",
         apellidos: "Revisor Final",
         nombres: "Usuario"}];
```

```
        array2=[{id:"72",nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 1",calificacion: "25.00000"},
        {id:"72",nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 2",calificacion: "15.00000"},
        {id:"72",nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 3",calificacion: "5.00000"}];
```

Como pueden ver en los dos arreglos tienen el campo id y es el mismo número, lo que quiero hacer es reconstruir el arreglo de tal forma que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
             arrayFinal=[{
             id: "72",
             rfc: "iyuiiygjgj",
             apellidos: "Revisor Final",
             nombres: "Usuario",
             nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 1",
             calificacion: "25.00000",
             nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 2",
             calificacion: "15.00000",
             nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 3",
             calificacion: "5.00000"}];
```

Lo único que logré fue hacer lo siguiente:

```
        arrayPrueba=[{id: "72",rfc: "iyuiiygjgj",apellidos: "Revisor Final",nombres: "Usuario"},
             {id:"72",nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 1",calificacion: "25.00000"},
             {id:"72",nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 2",calificacion: "15.00000"},
             {id:"72",nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 3",calificacion: "5.00000"}];
```

Entonces cuando traigo la información con jquery en un console.log(); me la trae de la siguiente forma:

```
        Id:72
        rfc:iyuiiygjgj
        nombres: Usuario
        apellidos: Revisor Final
        nombre_ejercicio:null
        calificacion:null
```

```
        Id:72
        rfc:iyuiiygjgj
        nombres: Usuario
        apellidos: Revisor Final
        nombre_ejercicio:Actividad 1
        calificacion: 25.00000
```

```
        Id:72
        rfc:iyuiiygjgj
        nombres: Usuario
        apellidos: Revisor Final
        nombre_ejercicio:Actividad 2
        calificacion: 25.00000
```

```
        Id:72
        rfc:iyuiiygjgj
        nombres: Usuario
        apellidos: Revisor Final
        nombre_ejercicio:Actividad 3
        calificacion: 25.00000
```

La información me la está duplicando, en la primer información me trae los datos del usuario solamente y en las otros datos me trae la información correcta pero en varios bloques.

Entonces por ello requiero

```
        arrayFinal=[{id: "72",rfc: "iyuiiygjgj",apellidos: "Revisor Final",nombres: 
        "Usuario",nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 1",calificacion: "25.00000",nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 
        2",calificacion: "15.00000",nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 3",calificacion: "5.00000"}];
```

En un solo índice tener toda la información, actualmente estoy usando una función que encontré aquí en el grupo que es la siguiente:

```
        function MergeArrays( key, val ) {
        var curr,
            idx,
            gcurr,
            gidx = 1,
            ret = [ ];
      
        while( gcurr = arguments[++gidx] ) {
          idx = -1;
      
          while( curr = gcurr[++idx] )
            if( curr[key] == val )
              ret.push( curr );
        }
      
        return ret;
      }
```

Esa función construye el arregló así:

```
        arrayPrueba=[{id: "72",rfc: "iyuiiygjgj",apellidos: "Revisor Final",nombres: "Usuario"},
             {id:"72",nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 1",calificacion: "25.00000"},
             {id:"72",nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 2",calificacion: "15.00000"},
             {id:"72",nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 3",calificacion: "5.00000"}];
```

Gracias por sus comentarios compañeros.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer creo que no es posible (en arrayFinal) ya que php/js o cualquier otro lenguaje de programación no va a poder distinguir entre las distintas propiedades *calificacion* y *nombre_ejercicio* ya que tienen el mismo nombre.

Es decir, si al final obtuvieses un array como el que quieres:

```
arrayFinal=[{
             id: "72",
             rfc: "iyuiiygjgj",
             apellidos: "Revisor Final",
             nombres: "Usuario",
             nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 1",
             calificacion: "25.00000",
             nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 2",
             calificacion: "15.00000",
             nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 3",
             calificacion: "5.00000"
}];
```

y luego quisieses modificar u obtener/extraer del objeto alguna de las propiedades *calificacion* y/o *nombre_ejercicio*, cómo puede saber el lenguaje de programación a cuál de ellas te refieres? cómo las distinguirías?

Creo que necesites lo que necesites, puedes conseguirlo a partir de *arrayPrueba*. Si lo que pretendes es agruparlos por el id, puedes construir un array de esta forma, por ejemplo:

```
arrayPrueba=[{
             id: "72",
             rfc: "iyuiiygjgj",
             apellidos: "Revisor Final",
             nombres: "Usuario"
             datos : [
                 {nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 1",calificacion: "25.00000"},
                 {nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 2",calificacion: "15.00000"},
                 {nombre_ejercicio: "Actividad 3",calificacion: "5.00000"},
             ]
}];
```

Comment: Hola Cooper, antes que nada agradezco tu tiempo y tu respuesta, tu idea me parece genial ya que de esa forma se insertan los datos justo en el índice que yo necesito, no importa que sea otro array, de tal forma puedo traer la información y solo saldrá una vez y no muchas como actualmente me las trae. Dejame intentar construir el arreglo de esa forma haber si puedo, no soy muy bueno en la construcción de arreglos ese tipo.  Gracias